# Access Apple Maps nearby locations vs text search in iOS MapKit

Tags: ios, swift, mapkit

I am attempting to search for nearby locations matching some criteria (e.g. "Bakery"). I am planning on using MKLocalSearch to find nearby locations. I know I can provide a search query. However, I have found that in Maps, searching for "Desserts" returns a different result than using Apple's feature for nearby locations and choosing "Desserts".

Is there any way I can search for "Desserts" the same way as Apple's nearby locations feature does?